# Java program compiles in eclipse but not netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

In eclipse this line of code compiles and the program runs fine.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) data, R.layout.message_list_item, from, to);
```

It gives the warning:

```
unchecked cast from ArrayList<Map> to List<? extends Map<String, ?>>
```

In netbeans however:

```
Incompatible types: ArrayList<Map> cannot be converted to List<? extends Map<String, ?>>
```

And then the runtime error:

```
error: inconvertible types
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) data, R.layout.message_list_item, from, to);
required: List<? extends Map<String,?>>
found:    ArrayList<Map>
```

Can someone please explain this difference in behaviour to me? Thanks.

Comment: You're most likely running 2 different versions of Java on the 2 IDEs. Check it.

Comment: Check your compiler settings for netbeans. By default in eclipse Unchecked Generic type operations give Warning, but it could be set to Error or Ignore (in Preferences -> Java ->Compiler ->Errors/Warnings)

Comment: I managed to run it but it threw that runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has it's own Java compiler while Netbeans uses the one from your JDK. They are compatible and both produce valid code but for some obscure features (especially in the area of generics), they aren't 100% compatible. Most of the time, the Eclipse compiler will be able to handle more complex cases.

Try to install Java 7 and use that for Netbeans. Oracle has fixed some bugs in the compiler.

**EDIT** After looking at the question again, I see a problem: You're mixing generic and raw types: You try to cast `Map` to `Map<String,?>`.

Try to use a generic type when you declare `data` instead of `ArrayList<Map>`. If that doesn't work, then you can use this workaround:

```
    @SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked", "rawtypes" } )
    java.util.List<? extends Map<String, ?>> tmp = (java.util.List<? extends Map<String, ?>>)((List) data);
```

This little trick strips all generics information from the right hand side before the compiler has a chance to use it against you.

Comment: In that case, you probably have found a bug in Java 7's javac. If you have a simple test case, you may want to report it.

Comment: Where do I report it?

Comment: OpenJDK would be a good place: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/web/bugzilla.html If you have a support contract with Oracle, ask for support. That will give the bug more attention.

Comment: You may also want to try with a pre-release of Java 8. If the bug is fixed there, chances are good you can ask them to backport the fix.

Comment: The problem persists running java version "1.8.0_20".  This code is no longer acceptable, though found in many examples.  What is an alternative to "List<? extends Map<String, ?>>" ??

Comment: Thanks, but I found the solution with my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855056/custom-view-layout-listmap-cannot-be-converted-to-list-extends-mapstrin

Answer (score 0):

Check both platforms and make sure you have the same JDK version running in both IDEs, that is most likely the problem.