# Custom View Layout - " List<Map> cannot be converted to List<? extends Map<String,?>> "

Tags: java, android

I have a custom list view which allows clicking on items in the list.

The code that worked well, similar to many examples on google's own site, and compiled successfully until more recent java, is this:

```
List<Map> myMapList = new ArrayList<Map>();
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
private ListView myListView;

for (int i = 0; i < mydata.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject t = mydata.getJSONObject(i);

        myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        myMap.put("field_1", t.getString("field_1"));

    .... (more of these)

        myMapList.add(myMap);
}


String[] layoutNames = new String[] { "field_1", "field_2", "field_3",
                                      "field_4", "field_5" };

int[] layoutIDs = new int[] { R.id.field_1, R.id.field_2, R.id.field_3, 
                              R.id.field_4, R.id.field_5};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
     (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) myMapList, R.layout.my_list_row, 
      layoutNames, layoutIDs );

    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

At first, warnings were given, but now it is a compile-time error.

```
error: incompatible types: List<Map> cannot be converted to List<? extends Map<String,?>>
```

So how to I feed my String / Integer combo into List<> with the new rules?

---

Solution Note:

Answer Goes to Aeshang, see below.  Note that this solution also gets rid of the need for the "(List>)" cast, so that line now reads:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
     myMapList, R.layout.my_list_row, layoutNames, layoutIDs );
```

Easier on the eyes, too.

Comment: Added the additional pieces, aside from click-actions and such.

Comment: No one is helping you cause you don't mark the answers ... if you mark the correct answer then you might start getting help ... consider it ...

Comment: Consider the tumbleweeds.  5 of my 13 questions have No Answers.  I do check them when they work - even if they get me 1/2 the way there, and I can fill in the blanks on reply for the next guy.

Comment: Just a suggestion bro ... even if the and doesn't work you can comment saying doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
List<Map> myMapList = new ArrayList<Map>();
```

to

```
List<Map<String, String>> myMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

Comment: Got it to compile.  Though a msg popped up: "Casting 'myMapList' to 'List<? extends Map<String, ?>>' is redundant.  Will test on the device now with and without that casting.

Comment: Yep.  Your solution got rid of the need for it.  I will edit above to this effect.  Thanks very much.